# Ionic toggle value stays the same

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I found this example of Toggle here:

I copied it to my project like

in my app.js

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope,$interval) {
 $scope.value = false;
  console.log('ContactCtrl started') ;

 $scope.toggleChange = function(){
   if($scope.value == false) {
   $scope.value = true;  
   }
   else
     $scope.value = false;
    console.log('testToggle changed to '+$scope.value);
   };
  });
```

In HTML:

```
<ion-view title="Log in" id="page12">
  <ion-content ng-controller="ContactCtrl" padding="true" class="has-header">
    <div id="settings-markdown6" style="text-align:center;" class="show-list-numbers-and-dots">
      <p style="color:#000000;font-size:23px;">Settings</p>
    </div>

     <ion-toggle ng-model=value ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>

  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

The issue is I'm getting the console logs but it seems the toggle stays always FALSE. Every time I press the toggle the console reports: "testToggle changed to false". What the problem that I don't see?

Update on posted solution:

[image: Not working solution]

Solution:

```
app.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope, $localStorage) {
  $scope.value = false;
  $scope.change = function() {
      console.log($scope.value);
  }
  });

<ion-toggle ng-model="value"  ng-checked="value" ng-change="change()"toggle-class="toggle-royal">Airplane Mode</ion-toggle>
```

Comment: yes, its a bug from ionic framework

Comment: What do you mean? Here : http://codepen.io/keval5531/pen/LVYROp?editors=1011#0 its working just fine

Comment: In this codepen they are doing it with custom code using function `$scope.toggleChange`, its not working automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `ng-click`:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="value" ng-click="value = !value">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
```

And you also don't need any function in controller.

---

**Update:** With a function call, it can be:

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="value" ng-click="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
```

```
$scope.toggleChange = function() {
    $scope.value = !$scope.value;
}
```

Comment: I will need the controller because in case of:
off->on : I would like to load a popup modal and do stuff
on->off : I would like to do some other stuff

Thats the concept

Comment: Solved Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

Use `ng-change` for updating the model

```
<ion-toggle ng-model="value" ng-change="toggleChange()">Test toggle</ion-toggle>
```

toggleChange function code

```
$scope.toggleChange = function(){
   $scope.value = !$scope.value
});
```

Comment: I tried your solution but is not working, check on the first question the gif image. Both solutions that you provided along with Mistalis solution, give the same result.